.Net Maui: Template reusing in CollectionView
I am developing an App for iOS with .Net MAUI 8.0 and having trouble understanding how the templates in a CollectionView are being re-used (and why).
I am having a Shell-Tab which contains a CollectionView (with infinite scrolling) which is using a DataTemplate ("ItemTemplate") to display the data. Within the template, an image and some information is shown (almost fills the whole screen), while part of the information is only visible when the "information"-area is expanded (see the expand-button on the right side):


What I expected was that for each entry within the CollectionView a new DataTemplate would be used. However, that is not the case. It seems like the DataTemplates (and their states) are being reused.
To be specific, only 3 DataTemplates are generated in the background from Maui. This can be seen with the following statement:
MyCollectionView.GetVisualTreeDescendants().Where(child => child is MyTemplate).Count()

So this leads to a lot of problems. For example, if I expand the "Information"-area on the first item, and scroll down the CollectionView, the "Information"-area of the fourth item (in the CollectionView) is also expanded, while the others keep the Information-area (as expected) collapsed. But this is just the tip of the iceberg, because sometimes the size of the controls within the Information-area are getting calculated wrongly.
Here's the definition of the CollectionView:
 <CollectionView
        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AdvertTemplateSelector}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Adverts}"
        Scrolled="OnCollectionViewScrolled"
        SelectionMode="None"
        VerticalOptions="Fill"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
        x:Name="AdvertsCollection">

            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    SnapPointsAlignment="Start"
                    SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        
 </CollectionView>

The DataTemplate contains more or less only simple properties, like all the tutorials within the microsoft-docs show.
I tried some workarounds, like calling PlatformSizeChanged() for the DataTemplates and stuff like that, but it just doesn't work like expected.
So my questions are:

Why is CollectionView reusing the DataTemplates?
Is there a way to force the CollectionView to use a "new" DataTemplate every time without recycling an old one?
Any other ideas / workarounds how I could proceed regarding my mentioned issues?

Thanks in advance.

Yes CollectionView reuse the cells. You may see here UICollectionViewController
